# sql grouping duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

So here is the code which is working fine but not grouping the duplicated values.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(driver.first_name, ' ', driver.last_name) AS [Driver Name],
    AVG(RATING.score) AS Average_Score,
    driver.driver_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(RATING.score) = 1 THEN 'Driver is very bad.'
        WHEN rating.score = 2 THEN 'Driver is bad.'
        WHEN RATING.score = 3 THEN 'Driver is okay.'
        WHEN RATING.score = 4 THEN 'Driver is good.'
        WHEN RATING.score = 5 THEN 'Driver is excellent.'
    END AS [Driver Performance]
FROM
    CALL
INNER JOIN 
    RATING ON CALL.rating_id = RATING.rating_id
INNER JOIN 
    DRIVER ON CALL.driver_id = DRIVER.driver_id
GROUP BY   
    driver.first_name, driver.last_name, driver.driver_id, rating.score
```

[image: As you can see]

As you can see mehmet cinar should had 3 average_score but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Drop `,rating.score` from GROUP BY.

Comment: @Serg when I do that I am getting an error." Column 'RATING.score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Caused from the case function lines.

Comment: to have consistent answer you should provide exact schema of your data, RDBMS you are using, the example data and expected result with explanation.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sure thing! I am using Microsoft SQL. I have a rating table which has ratings of the drivers. My main idea is getting average of the drivers ratings and evaluate them as Driver Performance -visible in the image-.My main table is CALL table which has the rating_id and driver_id in it. Im expecting to get 3 average_score for the driver named "mehmet cinar" but I couldnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use `avg(RATING.score)` across all the CASE options consistently. Next, the aggregated column shouldn't be on the `GROUP BY` list.

```
select  CONCAT(driver.first_name,' ',driver.last_name)as [Driver Name]
, avg(RATING.score) as Average_Score,driver.driver_id,
CASE WHEN avg(RATING.score) = 1 THEN 'Driver is very bad.'
  WHEN avg(RATING.score) = 2 THEN 'Driver is bad.'
  WHEN avg(RATING.score) = 3 THEN 'Driver is okay.'
  WHEN avg(RATING.score) = 4 THEN 'Driver is good.'
  WHEN avg(RATING.score) = 5 THEN 'Driver is excellent.'
END AS [Driver Performance]
FROM CALL
INNER JOIN RATING ON CALL.rating_id=RATING.rating_id
INNER JOIN DRIVER ON CALL.driver_id=DRIVER.driver_id
GROUP BY driver.first_name,driver.last_name,driver.driver_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: So your have different combinations of `driver.first_name,driver.last_name,driver.driver_id`  in your data. Probably you can drop driver.driver_id fom SELECT and GROUP BY. Or may by use `min/max/count( driver.driver_id)` in SELECT.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Dropping the driver_id from SELECT and GROUP BY,solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code shows how to correctly group by driver and compute the average score

```sql
create table driver (id int identity primary key, fullname nvarchar(450))
create table rating (id int identity primary key, driverId int, score float)
insert driver values ('Fabio'), ('Laura')
insert rating values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)
select driver.fullname FullName, avg(rating.score) Score
    from driver join rating on driver.id = rating.driverId group by driver.id, driver.fullname
```

Result

| FullName | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Fabio | 2.5 |
| Laura | 4.5 |

Fabio